# How do I disable the input cursor blink in a new X session?

Tags: x11, vnc, xvfb, xfce

I am running a some browser regression in a new X session using 'Xvfb' and 'x11vnc'.

My window manager is Xfce 4.16 and the OS is Fedora 35.

To launch these I am running the following;

```
`which Xfvb` :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24
xfwm4 --replace
x11vnc -shared -xkb -forever -rfbauth ./vncpassfile -rfbport 5901 -display :1
```

This all works correctly, I can connect with vncviewer and watch our regression run if I so desire.

The problem occurs when we are capturing an input field, depending on the timing we sometimes capture the input cursor.

I have disabled cursor blinking via Xfce's Keyboard settings on my main desktop. Which works great (I can visit google.com on chrome and the input cursor doesn't blink).

Unfortunately this setting doesn't seem to be honored by the new session started above and the cursor continues to blink.

I have tried opening a terminal and the keyboard setting menu to disable cursor blinking inside the new session but it says it is already disabled (matches my main desktop).

Am I doing something silly?

I could set the `caret-color` to be `transparent` via css, but I really want to understand why I can't disable the cursor in my new X session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was because I was not starting xfsettingsd for the new window manager. Once I started a new xfsettingsd it works as expected.

Comment: A little more context here would be nice especially for search-ability, like that it's XFCE (if it in fact is.) or which distro, if you think that mattered.